# How add field according to generic type value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to make a tiny front-end API lib for a project of mine with the mindset on learning the TypeScript type-system.

Suppose I define a union type that has the REST methods:

```js
type Methods = 'POST' | 'GET' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE' | 'PUT';
```

And that I have tied the headers with the methods using the following interface:

```js
interface QueryOptions<Method extends Methods = 'GET'> {
    headers?: RequestInit['headers'];
    method?: Method;
}
```

In which `RequestInit['headers']` has the same type as the headers used by the browser's fetch API.

Now, `body` happens only in `POST` requests thus I want a function that automatically infers if a `body` is needed or if `params` are needed.

I came up with:

```js
type QueryFactory = <M extends Methods>(
    queryOptions: QueryOptions<M>,
) => <T, P extends M extends 'POST' ? Record<string, unknown> : Record<string, string>>(options: {
    id?: string | number;
    params?: M extends 'POST' ? never : P;
    body: M extends 'POST' ? P : never;
    route: string;
}) => Promise<T>;
```

If I implement that interface to something such as

```js
const queryParams = <T extends Record<string, string>>(url: string, params?: T): string =>
    params && Object.keys(params).length > 0 ? `${url}?${new URLSearchParams(params).toString()}` : url;

const queryFactory: QueryFactory = (options) => async ({ route, id, ...rest }) => {
    route = id ? `${route}/${id}` : route;
    const input =
        options.method !== `POST` && typeof rest.params !== `undefined` ? queryParams(route, rest.params) : route;
    const init = options.method === `POST` ? { ...options, body: JSON.stringify(rest.body) } : options;
    const response = await fetch(input, init);

    return response.json();
};
```

With this I can now do:

```js
const query = {
    post: queryFactory({ method: `POST` }),
    get: queryFactory({ method: `GET` }),
    put: queryFactory({ method: `PUT` }),
    patch: queryFactory({ method: `PATCH` }),
    delete: queryFactory({ method: `DELETE` }),
};


const books = query.get<{ books: string[] }, { author: string }>({ route: `/books`, params: { author: 'Foo Bar' } });
```

I think that my `QueryFactory` type is wrong because the last code line `query.get` complains that the field `body: never` is missing and `queryParams(route, rest.params)` complains that `rest.params` potentialy extends from `Record<string, unknown>` while it only needs to extend from `Record<string, string>`.

I am hitting the limits of my TypeScript type-system knowledge and do not see how to fix this inference issue. I have copied the code into: [TypeScript PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAzlAvFA5ABQHkBlAFRygB9cBxAUTMtzwEESBhACXKpwBFaAMvVrcmAVTIBuALAAoOQEsAdsAgAnAGYBDAMbQAigFd1IAmGAKkStAB44iVFAgAPVUvSx4yD9hx0yAHxQAN5yUOFQCBBaKOpoAPwAXFAAShAAjsZowACSSgrAANo4UTFxOAC6MrIRUAC2XqhJng4o1QC+cnKgkFBGJgBiusBIaiBYUHZOrhDuGPbeaAEAFGERmSZmFlZoyf1jW5bWdgEANHIAlFhBNiSnUHjTbh4wT7Me+MQM8akQOqMoGzZNTKADm90MSgA1kokAB3JRBZJpf5qQHAsH3DFKUEBFZIcxHXYhNbhBQoZrY0GMJSGOoAI3U1VqYC0ai0dQSyVeLmeGE+pHIPyUEAAbuooMk8MyIvTUCBuW85kwvkKHpKoCLxWoZeE1EhDKpklSOldMEE8Pq6go0BBbgFqnJ-tZgFANmM8GyORhsLclR4UQCgcAQTisSGwXjloY1AAbY0RsNQVnsznJEgXBOh6nm0lQAj0gBWf2AADooRAQGhlinvRdS7HZqDEFAggAGKA-AAGABJgjHY+14n2RXCoGIUgIiNE1DoEJ7U9Xa5z6yMiInQcsLu0uxqB47ZM7sm7jGMhjoRmM9qeQOfL+NsMsCdtrGaglo0CAlDooMtglB9UNCB7nJe5S3AtQIGPdo3xJGoIkA1QJnJTsoF7YJEIgdoAHo+3JHcNUw3UoCPV1lDAQ0sDzWpnyJUsGlaKAAEJMGwLtCFIXcADIuKgHoICQDQAKgstlwwFi2MhWINGUCAUF3H53RABdvWWTD7kg7JSzEq5kiIvNSKgZQCgmWidnoxoUCwVi0I4kgFJCKBwNLMzrHuOUUAVKAACkiAIAA5UsqQUDQQDUkTSw8kArnaDVXLQYjDM0sAdmgbAtDhLQTI0eA52WcjDRA-JgAuA9akg4AYyUYS0BS6wIFLQs0CsLcOgPQylImUJ4PCFLsmSJS71GML-wY7xknYr5dxg84eqgUF4AGm8hrGP96ksib-Gmi5ZpZQ0lsGYZhrWsbUAmvAJG23aIlZYA5wOs8jtW0aNts1hOCuvNYkbI0T0Oi9jpe1oJv4IQSFoT7ZHadqdldOUkChH0-rGUsFuAGx-3hxGszBQoKigdp7n-LRDWQNQcZxAmVn-TCJuwrG0C7e4xOSYnSdGCaBiQJAoAAITZaaCdKrpDx2JBGwbJBNwZi4RZcFK1FdaSSdjV0lOqIA)

Comment: The term you're looking for is "discriminated union", you can read more about it [in this article](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions).

Comment: You can't specify required parameters after optional parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typescript provides powerful so-called [differentiating types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) which allow TS to discriminate automatically between one of several types if you have field values which are known at compile time.

In this case you can start by defining a base interface with the common properties and then sub-interfaces with the variations. (Note: In general, TS does not require that the types all extend a common base, all that matters is that they all contain the discriminating field with an explicit value).

```
type Method = 'POST' | 'GET' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE' | 'PUT';

interface BaseQueryOptions<M extends Method> {
    method?: M
    headers?: RequestInit['headers']
    id?: string
    route: string
}

type BodyType = Record<string, unknown>
type ParamsType = Record<string, string>

interface PostOptions<T extends BodyType> extends BaseQueryOptions<'POST'> {
    body: T
}

interface DefaultOptions<T extends ParamsType> extends BaseQueryOptions<'GET' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE' | 'PUT'> {
    params?: T
}
```

Then we define a union (here called simply `Options`). It is the types in this union which TS will discriminate between for us. We also need a few utility types for strong typing.

```
type BodyOrParams = BodyType | ParamsType
type AsBodyType<T> = T extends BodyType ? T : never
type AsParamsType<T> = T extends ParamsType ? T : never

type Options<P extends BodyOrParams> = PostOptions<AsBodyType<P>> | DefaultOptions<AsParamsType<P>>
```

Now, we can write a function which accepts `Options` and typescript can create automatic type guards, that is, it can infer the type automatically when we check the value of `method` in an `if` or `switch` statement.

```
async function query<T extends Record<string, unknown>, P extends BodyOrParams > (options: Options<P>): Promise<T> {
    let { route, id } = options
    route = id ? `${route}/${id}` : route;

    switch (options.method) {
        case 'POST':
            // TS knows here that options is PostOptions
            const postOptions = { ...options, body: JSON.stringify(options.body) }
           return (await fetch(route, postOptions)).json()

        case 'GET':
        case 'PATCH':
        case 'DELETE':
        case 'PUT':
            // TS knows here that options is DefaultOptions
            const params = queryParams(route, options.params)
            return (await fetch(params, options)).json()

        default:
            throw 'No method specified'
    }
}
```

And now we have very strong typing when invoking `query`:

```
query<{ books: string[] }, { author: string }>(
{
    method: 'GET',
    route: `/books`,
    params: { author: 'Foo Bar' }
}); // Works
    
query<{ books: string[] }, { author: string }>({ 
    method: 'GET',
    route: `/books`,
    params: { foo: 'Foo Bar' }
}); // ERROR 'foo' does not exist on { author: string }
    
query<any, { book: any }>({
    method: 'POST',
    route: `/books`,
    body: { book: 'Foo Bar' }
}); // works
    
query<any, { book: any }>({ 
    method: 'POST',
    route: `/books`,
    params: { book: 'Foo Bar' }
}); // ERROR params does not exist on PostOptions
    
query<any, { book: any }>({
    method: 'POST',
    route: `/books`,
    body: { author: 'Foo Bar' }
}); // ERROR author does not exist on { book: any }
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATKBeKByACgeQGUAVLKAH2wHEBRE87HAQSIGEAJUirAEWoBla1TgwCqJANwAoSQEsAdsAgAnAGYBDAMbQAQmoDOEAIoBXZSDxhgMpHL0AeGFAgAPRXJR7Y8ZCgB8UAG9JKBCoAFtvVAB%20AC5YYNCECDUUZT1YqAAlCABHUz1gAEk5GWAAbSwklLSsAF0EkJkUDIKleQBzBqglJGNFONaOyQBfaVBIKG1UECJwaExsjSQlFDtBuXaAGihjOQBrOSQAdzlfSXHoHDUlNTC9WYmFiCWVteA2je319rPZBWV1FooDgkAULFYbPYiE5XBB3J4pigZnN-C43B5JvojKYlOZLNZbHZcIQSP4gqEoAAjaZxIgjaTyRSqTTQbgQdTGAA2wHBBKhMPRniuNzuDwgqNh8MxBhMZl5kKJNDoXCYrA49B4-EEwlwYiwZK6YGut3StPp5zmk2meCUwpNGCtSLF9DtormFomjD0iORkDsRH8mGhaLhGJ9zqiUGhcTkEAAbsoPdAva77nN-YGowLQ0LjW6JpHo1BYwmlGNLfLCThs1KfTbU5mQWD8QqveH0zhfP4KGyOdzK-YU3m037O78VLsNBC5FA8mZU1AABTGJScgbvDrbI0ivRxRbLVbfL4bjaZgLDACUgS6SngK5neEpACtnsAAHR7CAgPSL7cmi9vpycLtIgUD%20AADFAkYAAYACQBCunLDFE8GxkcUAiJkfAEMkSgaAgqa-sOAHAEgBAnu0i4XsM0FQHEiFSKMkj6CAcgaFAE5sdOs44iA-o1hi%206vEeOz7IcJy%20Ns1YhrW1q2sOYFLkgLa2HEA52J2F5xDgPRhDIBgZteFJAcAgTdL0ijbE0UDDA6ynTnoN4WfMUDWTB8E9H0EDDAA9PBTQ0XR5leVIXR6EcpT4UpKl6G%20ESIKgV7khSoQaFiDAklgMRdCloQ%20T5UYEFABzHJ4SS3lAiBqKZ9l8q5QqgjyMU5blUBLLYplgI1A4OgEUBvgNtWQts1JInEABSBB4AAcm%203wyCoICLkNthvqNIBXqMrUUrewD3kuahHGopQcfA%20GLp5llQF1zYOReAFPnoNhUdI21pQYVC0FlLUhO90C4Mw7DfW96WagIRBCNlIMfbqJBQ9teUFUQRUlUcZXKNAVU1TF9VQL2ahck1Dk-Sl7UFNdCmYHOuKEZdEDbCtsV-ncF4kztd5KDOi6HcdpkqGdCBETuDMxfdb6Pc9rMk6kfbAPDCOVQgPToVg01IOEkRoHokAaAtMgQCgWBdKMTEUtTfF9dSSB7LuUDfGUtQ2dsfUEwlSjrh87Q2b4i5dMluXxT4cRYEqWCbCTdNxNBPlWzb0Hh9tzO2y7fTIO72AAGJIOruhKKQW2hJeUjbV05t2Jb2c2x7HQO07Zmu2n1cbN7i59STgeoMHocJ61kdQNHsd6PHJNJ3EfUqNnwdZzn1z58bF7F61pe8XYahyCAztUpXcRryALf%20ylHcoMH%20DEGHEfOVHMeV0PPe5etY9b9bU-Z5iec2fPi%205cvZir%20vm%20xx3uvfeUB26axPplO%20KU%204DxvsPROw5H6AMzq-XOc8KRFxJj-XEf8N5mWQbvfeYCErHwymfKBO1L792vtbW%20JMH711TssF%20M934FxCEXIAA)

Comment: It is not really a solution since it removes what causes the problem. `PostOptions` should have a body `B` which extends from `Record<string, unknown>` and `DefaultOptions` should have `params?: P` where `P` extends from `Record<string, string>`. The idea is to enforce the the correct type `params` and `body`. If I add both generic types to `PostOptions` and `DefaultOptions` then how should I discriminate the `Options` type in order to put the correct generic? I pressume the `Options` type will have a generic of the form: `Options<T extends Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, string>>` ?

Comment: @dll It does enforce the types you want. Play around in the playground link. See what happens when you try to call the methods with the wrong options.

Comment: @dll `PostOptions` does have a `body` and does not have `params`, while `DefaultOptions` has a `params` but not `body`.

Comment: @dll Also, `Options` is not generic. It has no template parameter. It is a union.

Comment: Yes for sure but I cannot have the type safety by specifying the type as such: `query.post<{ username: string; password: string}>({ method: 'POST', route: '/', body: { a: 1 } })` which is a bummer. It is an error that could be caught by TypeScript. I wonder even if it is possible to achieve such thing in TypeScript.

Comment: @dll If in the playground link you call `queryFunction({ method: 'POST', route: '' })` it will give you an error `Property 'body' is missing in type '{ method: "POST"; route: string; }'`, and if you call `queryFunction({ method: 'GET', route: '', body: {} })` you will get the error `'body' does not exist in type 'DefaultOptions'`

Comment: Yes, the body and params separation works, but at the expense of losing the type safety of the params & body. The solution that you provided does not work for the last line of code at the bottom of the initial question: `query.get<{ books: string[] }, { author: string }>({ route: `/books`, params: { author: 'Foo Bar' } });`. This is because the solution you provided does not handle those two generics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220571/discussion-between-ccarton-and-dll).

Answer (score 1):

never is not the thing you want here you want to remove the properties of the options Object so something like Omit

so assume we have the options Object

```js
interface Options<P>{
    id?: string | number;
    params?: P;
    body: P;
    route: string;
}
```

we can get different Object with omit from that like

```js
type PostOption<P> = Omit<Options<P>, 'params'>
type GetOptions<P> =  Omit<Options<P>, 'body'>
```

and then declare the function definition

```js
declare function queryFactory<M extends Methods>(
    queryOptions: QueryOptions<M>,
): <T, K extends M extends 'POST' ? Record<string, unknown> : Record<string, string>>
(options: M extends 'POST' ? PostOption<K> : GetOptions<K>) =>  Promise<K>
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAzlAvFA5ABQHkBlAFRygB9cBxAUTMtzwEESBhACXKpwBFaAMvVrcmAVTIBuALAAoOQEsAdsAgAnAGYBDAMbQAigFd1IAmGAKkStAB44iVFAgAPVUvSx4yD9hx0yAHxQAN5yUOFQCBBaKOpoAPwAXFAAShAAjsZowACSSgrAANo4UTFxOAC6MrIRUAC2XqhJng4o1QC+cooq6tp6UGYWVrZ4AaE1EQoozdlqygDmjEqGdQBG6tW1YFpqWnUJyXibEauoIIfH4WpIhqrJswsdXbKgkFB4SNmDlko2o1gDOoFGzfYZ-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-TskMvjbIoqj2ho8T6J80zmPslcnK4wdeOM-jBJhETPNqyTfNkhSlPHEKso0viABZCpMPD4DKjqKvmCzqqsuqpL9Jr2JuZy2tcqECXOEJvKkwc-KGwLgonZDZCAA)

Comment: While the type safety works the implementation of `QueryFactory` does not work. The fields `params` and `body` are not recognized.